# Respond to PDF load failure in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript in a website, I'm loading a PDF from my server, which is being generated on demand. This is the code (using a public PDF for demo purposes):

```
window.open('https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~shmat/shmat_urls.pdf', '_blank');
```

I want to be able to detect whether the call was successful or not, so I can update a status accordingly. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you set a variable to your `window.open`, like this:

```
var otherWindow = window.open('https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~shmat/shmat_urls.pdf', '_blank');
```

Then you can access it with `otherWindow.opener`. If the page fails to load, `otherWindow` will be `null`, and you can handle that with a status update, or whatever you'd like to do.

More info about `window.open` is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).